# Nested Query, inside LIKE or REGEXP query

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using MySQL 5.1.34

I'd like to use an Ad Hoc query, where I can nest a query inside a `LIKE` or `REGEXP` statement.

For Example: I have a tables groups & sheets. dept_id is a foreign key to groups.

`SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]](SELECT DISTINCT dept_id FROM sheets)[[:>:]]";`

`SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name like "%(SELECT DISTINCT dept_id FROM lotnumqcs)%";`

I realize I haven't accounted for `|`, `OR` statements in the `REGEXP`. That is included in this question, how can I account for that?

Answer (score 0):

<del>I may be missing something significant here, but I'm pretty sure you can't do what you hope....</del>

EDIT

Assuming you're trying to *emulate* the functionality described by your bespoke SELECT syntax, you might try:

```
/* 
   set @options to regex sequence group of distinct values of sheets.dept_id

   note: for completeness, each value should be properly escaped per regex rules.
*/

SET @options=CONCAT('[[:<:]](',(
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(did SEPARATOR '|') 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dept_id AS did FROM sheets) AS sheetsa
),')[[:>:]]');

SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name REGEXP @options;
```

which I successfully tested using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int);

INSERT INTO t1 (a,b) VALUES (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1);

SET @options=CONCAT( '[[:<:]](', ( 
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tb SEPARATOR '|') 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT b AS tb FROM t1) AS ta
), ')[[:>:]]' );

SELECT @options; /* '[[:<:]](0|1)[[:>:]]' */

SELECT '0' REGEXP @options;            /* 1 = true  */

SELECT '1' REGEXP @options;            /* 1 = true  */

SELECT '2' REGEXP @options;            /* 0 = false */

SELECT ' a ba 1 c d ' REGEXP @options; /* 1 = true  */

SELECT ' a ba1c d' REGEXP @options;    /* 0 = false */

SELECT ' a ba 1c d' REGEXP @options;   /* 0 = false */

SELECT ' a ba1 c d' REGEXP @options;   /* 0 = false */

SELECT ' a ba 2 c d' REGEXP @options;  /* 0 = false */
```

Comment: Note: You won't be able to do the same with LIKE since its argument doesn't support alternation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something to the effect of...

```
select groups.* from groups join sheets on name regexp CONCAT("[[:<:]]",dept_id,"[[:>:]]")
```

Can't vouch for the regex itself, but the concept should work. Like can be used in this manner as well. Consider that each value of groups.sheets would be evaluated against a regular expression based off each dept_id.

Comment: How would LIKE work here? Since it has no concept of word boundaries, I'm pretty sure LIKE '% foo %' wouldn't match ' ,foo ', ' foo.' or ' (foo) '. Am I missing something?

Comment: Curse my tunnel vision! What I meant was that the like expression LIKE could be used in a similar context... LIKE (in mysql, anyway) would be a poor choice if word boundaries were a factor.